# Error while installing VSTO file - A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce, office-interop, outlook-addin

When I try install our VSTO (outlook) file on machine 1 for user a, it works fine but for user b it gives below exception.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        VSTO 4.0
Date:          03/10/2016 12:50:59
Event ID:      4096
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      NAME_OF_COMPUTER
Description:
Customization URI: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MAIN_FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/OUTLOOK PLUGIN.vsto
Exception: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)


************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007001F): A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.DownloadAddIn(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1026 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60724.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.233 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1026 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1032 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1036 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60724.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60724.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1026 built by: RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 10.0.60724.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Deployment
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1039 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1015 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Security
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1031 (RTMGDR.030319-1000)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Security/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Security.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------



Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="VSTO 4.0" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49154">4096</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-10-03T11:50:59.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1179761</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>COMPUTER_NAME</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Customization URI: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MAIN_FOLDER/SUB_FOLDER/OUTLOOK PLUGIN.vsto
Exception: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)


************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007001F): A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.DownloadAddIn(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

Any idea?

[More information on query](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8d88dc77-37a4-4520-9f75-30a597a7615e/error-while-installing-vsto-file-a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning-exception?forum=vsto)

Enviroment:- Remote desktop service server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are files that are read-only that block ClickOnce from installing. The error is often not related to a device, but simply caused by installer obstructions where files cannot be deleted/overwritten using the ClickOnce engine.

It might be needed to clear out a previous installation properly manually that is blocking the ClickOnce engine (maybe clear the ClickOnce cache also).

Comment: Hi Maarten, I have checked all required permissions and that's not an issue. I tried clearing cache as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

We just cracked the issue. We found that user a's profile was dodgy. We removed particular profile and created new one, and it worked fine!

Still we are in process to find out what was “dodgy” about the profile.

Thanks for help.